# What's the risk of installing Cyanogen Mod on unsupported phone?

Tags: cyanogenmod

My device is not listed as supported on website [www.cyanogenmod.com/devices](http://www.cyanogenmod.com/devices). I have ZTE Skate, and some other ZTEs are listed, but not mine. 
Is it possible to install the mod on Skate, and what's the risk? If phone is not listed, does it mean, that it was just not tested, or the mod wouldn't work?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They have an **Unofficial** version of CyanogenMod for Skate [here](http://android.modaco.com/topic/345117-cyanogenmod-7-for-zte-skate-updated-0601/). I don't know what would happen if you tried to install version for another model.

Comment: Other than hard-brick!

Answer (score 19):

It means that in all probability it won't work. There are a lot of factors at play, but if it installs correctly there's a good chance it won't boot. Problems that could occur include:

- Your hardware will likely not have proper drivers. If it shares drivers with other devices then it may work, but otherwise various parts of the hardware will simply fail to function.
- The partition layout may be different, which could cause the install itself to fail if partition sizes are very different.
- The kernel from another device may not run on your device's processor.
- The boot image may not be configured and packaged properly for your device.

If the above all manage to be identical, then the system may boot and function, but it's generally pretty unlikely.

Comment: Regarding the device's processor, doesn't it depend on the architecture (like for Windows, Linux)? i.e. if it works for one ARM device, it works for all of them (but not for x86 processors like Intel Atoms)? Or are there other differences between processors in the case of Android?

Comment: There can actually be differences. The problem is less with the architecture itself, though, and more with the fact that mobile chips contain much more than just a processor (hence "System on a Chip"). The various components will need different drivers and so forth, which can cause complications. Different manufacturers may also support varying proprietary extensions to the ARM spec, just as Intel and AMD have their own extensions to x86 and such.